# Is it possible to share a local git repository between multiple OS?

Tags: git, share, local

I had once shared a git repository between FreeBSD and Windows. I somehow got it messed up.

I'm wondering if it is possible to successfully share a git repo between different versions of Git (including different platforms, and so on)?

Comment: Can't you just fetch and push from/to some common remote?

Comment: Generally speaking, what you describe is very much part of why git is useful. It indeed lets you work on the same repo from completely different OSes, provided they can run git of course.

Comment: It's unwise to share the *index* across different bootups / runs of different OSes, because the `stat` cache data that Git stuffs into the index are OS-dependent. But you can share the underlying repository.

Comment: @tkausl Yes and no. I don't want to share code with 3rd party service providers. I do have a private internet server, but I can't install git on it, so I use NFS for push and pull. I still haven't figured out how to wrap NFS into SSH, though.

Comment: @torek You could perhaps elaborate as an answer, and give a few pros and cons, when you get the time?

Comment: Microsoft basically messed up my whole concept. They recommend installing Git-scm, but the page states they no longer support that. It's the latest version of VS 2019. I don't know what's going on. It's why I'm thinking just keeping stuff on thumbdrives - for which apparently there is a version of git, or I am quite mistaken.